# Symfony2 / Doctrine - create entity only in the test environment

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to create some entities that would run only in test environment, during my unit tests. I dont think that there is some ebbded solution (am I wrong?), so probably another way is to create entities in the test folderand use them.

But there is something that I dont understand. Symfony sets the `BundleName\Entity` folders as folders where entities are, and `Tests/Entity` folder will not work with my entities. So, how do I explicitly set my `Tests/Entity` folder to work (read/install/register entities) in my test case? I assume this is made by configurating of doctrine entity manager?

Comment: Try to access your entity with full path like `Company\BundleName\Tests\Entity\SomeEntity`

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? What's the usecase?

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov to create test entities without mocking

Comment: Why on earth would you need to mock entities?

Comment: @ElnurAbdurrakhimov to test repository. I dont have entity implementation in my bundle, but have an abstract one. So, to test repository I need real (test) implementation of my abstract entity.

Comment: @forgottenbas, does not work - will give an error like `The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces `

Comment: I faced a similar issue, the solution may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177029/add-a-namespace-to-an-already-configured-entitymanager


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177029/add-a-namespace-to-an-already-configured-entitymanager

Answer (score 2):

Found this function in one of my projects, may be it can help you a bit. This function create new EntityManager, where you can define your entities namespace.

```
/**
 * @return EntityManager
 */
public static function createTestEntityManager()
{
    if (!class_exists('PDO') || !in_array('sqlite', \PDO::getAvailableDrivers())) {
        self::markTestSkipped('This test requires SQLite support in your environment');
    }
    $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
    $config->setEntityNamespaces(array('SerializerBundleTests' => 'Top10\SerializerBundle\Tests\Entity'));
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
    $config->setProxyDir(\sys_get_temp_dir());
    $config->setProxyNamespace('SerializerBundleTests\Entity');
    $config->setMetadataDriverImpl(new AnnotationDriver(new AnnotationReader()));
    $config->setQueryCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());
    $config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());

    $params = array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
        'memory' => true,
    );

    return EntityManager::create($params, $config);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think that Doctrine's entity manager doesn't allow you to add mapping for additional entities on the fly.

As a "crutchy" workaround, you could create an additional bundle that contains entities you want to use with your tests, then leave your Symfony2 config for the test environment the same (if you have "auto_mapping" set to true; see [this reference document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)), while changing you orm config for dev and prod environment. You'll need to disable auto mapping and specify the bundles explicitly, excluding the bundle with your test-only entities from "mappings".

Or maybe you [don't even need to specify the value of "auto_mapping"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). The relevant part of your config ("entity_managers", "mappings") for the dev\prod environment should look somewhat similar to the one in the cookbook entry.

Again, I wish to emphasize that I'm not 100% sure that this answer is correct, as my knowledge of Symfony2 has become a bit fuzzy.