# Symfony2 environment specific doctrine mappings configuration

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I've got a test bundle which has some doctrine entities. In AppKernel I added this bundle only to the dev and test environments and also made the mapping definitions for doctrine in the config.yml. The problem is in prod environment doctrine can't find the entities as the bundle isn't loaded in kernel. I don't want to load the test bundle in prod env.
I also have other entities defined in different bundles for doctrine so I'd switch the test bundle off in the config_prod.yml or set it to null - is it possible somehow? I don't want to copy and redefine the whole mappings array/list in config_prod.yml.

Comment: why you don't create the mapping in config_dev.yml ?

Comment: I'd like to avoid duplicating the mappings array, rather unset the one I don't need in prod.

Comment: are you using doctrine `auto_mapping` ?

Comment: @ra_htial: no, I'm not

Comment: you can create another doctrine entity manager mapping only your test bundle http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html .

Comment: maybe this question like yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651875/symfony2-doctrine-create-entity-only-in-the-test-environment

Comment: creating another EM is a bit overkill i guess ...

Comment: My solution is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177029/add-a-namespace-to-an-already-configured-entitymanager