# Add a namespace to an already configured EntityManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I've got an EntityManager instance fully configured and working. The question is how to add an additional namespace to this EM?

```
$em->getConfiguration()->addEntityNamespace('MyGreatBundle', 'My\GreatBundle\Entity');
```

This does not work, throws the following:

> Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: The class 'My\GreatBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue, had to add the driver too:

```
$namespace = 'My\GreatBundle\Entity';
$configuration = $em->getConfiguration();
$annotationDriver = new AnnotationDriver(
    $this->container->get('annotation_reader'),
    [__DIR__ . '/../Entity']
);

/** @var MappingDriverChain $driver */
$driver = $configuration->getMetadataDriverImpl();
$driver->addDriver($annotationDriver, $namespace);

$configuration->addEntityNamespace('MyGreatBundle', $namespace);
```